# Azure App Services Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, windows-10-universal

Has anyone been able to figure out authentication using Azure App Services?

For some strange reason it is no longer handling refresh tokens like it used to in Mobile Services, the token I'm now caching expires in 1 hour, this is useless.

It's a C# UWP app, I'm using Microsoft Account as the login, I've been told to use the OneDrive API to login and retrieve the token and then use that to login to App Services, that doesn't work for me either, with an error like "you do not have permission to access the directory".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The 1 hour expiration of the login token is a known issue a fix is on the way.  If you can provide more information about the "you do not have permission to access the directory" issue, we might be helpful in finding a workaround. Would you be able to provide an HTTP trace for when you get this error?  Also, try turning on application logging for your app in the management portal and see if there are any interesting warning/error messages.

Comment: Is the OneDrive SDK or the Mobile App Client throwing the "you do not have permission to access the directory"? message?

Comment: A Phillip in a post on MSDN answered this, guessing it was you lol.
But basically, I was using "authentcationToken" as the key in my JObject, I should have used "access_token", which works and now allows me to log in to App Services using the token obtained from OneDrive.

However I'd like to note, that the documentation specifically says to use "authenticationToken" and NOT "access_token" for Microsoft Accounts, this appears to be false, and is what led to the permission issue. Documentation relating to MobileServices/AppServices have been very confusing as of late.

Comment: Also, I'm glad to hear that the 1 hour expiry is an "issue" and that a fix is on the way. I actually used one of my Azure support tickets for this, so it appears I won't be getting a resolution on it until you guys fix the issue. Can you give me some more info regarding this issue? Is it isolated or is everyone experiencing it? Any ETA on a fix?

Comment: Yeah, the "authenticationToken" used to be the only one exposed by the older live SDKs.  All the docs need updated to show "access_token" which as far as I can tell is all the OneDrive SDK gives you.

Comment: Just to update, the "fix" has been deployed. You can find information on how to refresh tokens here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

Answer (score 1):

A solution for App Service Mobile, the update to MobileService. There should now be a [solution](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/)

The code replicated here is:

```
async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
try
{
    return await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("values");
}
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
{
    if (e.Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

// Calling /.auth/refresh will update the tokens in the token store
// and will also return a new mobile authentication token.
JObject refreshJson = (JObject)await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync(
    "/.auth/refresh",
    HttpMethod.Get,
    null);

string newToken = refreshJson["authenticationToken"].Value<string>();
App.MobileService.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
    = newToken;
return await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("values");
}
```

Hope it saves somebody time !